# Customize in filename rails issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to customize the format when i'm saving to xls :

- I want help customizing=  "Date" + "ejecutive selected" + ".xls"

My models

```
class Policy < ActiveRecord::Base
   unloadable
   belongs_to :ejecutive
   has_many :policy

   def self.search(search)
    if search
      find(:all, :conditions => ["ejecutive_id = ? ", search.to_i  ] )
    else
      find(:all)
    end
   end
end

class Ejecutive < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :policies
end
```

Here is my controller.
Here i put my format that i'm trying to customize with date + ejecutive selected + .xls

```
class PolicyManagement::PolicyController < ApplicationController
    def generate_print_ejecutive_comercial
       @ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)
       @search = Policy.search(params[:search])
       @policies = @search.paginate( :page => params[:page], :per_page =>10)
       @results= Policy.search(params[:search])

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xls { send_data render_to_string(:partial=>"report_by_ejecutive"), :filename => Date + @ejecutives.name"reporte.xls" }
      end  
end
```

Here is my view

```
<% form_tag :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action =>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial", :method => 'get' do %>
    <%= select_tag "search", options_for_select(@ejecutives.collect {|t| [t.name.to_s+" "+t.lastname1.to_s,t.id]}) %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

 Results
     <% @policies.each do |policy| %>
     <p> <%= policy.num_policy%> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.name %> </p>
     <p> <%= policy.ejecutive.last_name %> </p>
     <% end %>
     <%= will_paginate @policies %>

 <%= link_to "Export", :controller=>"policy_management/policy",:action=>"generate_print_ejecutive_comercial" ,:format=>"xls",:search => params[:search],:page => params[:page] %>
```

I tried this

```
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.xls { send_data render_to_string(:partial=>"report_by_ejecutive"), :filename => Date + @ejecutive.name + ".xls" }
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot `+` something to the `Date` class or a specific date like `Date.today`. But the following works.

```
:filename => "#{Date.today}#{@ejecutive.name}.xls"
```

`"#{something}"` evaluates `something`, calls `to_s` on the result and inserts its into the string.

Comment: i used your code and got undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: i change it for @ejecutives.name and i got undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x7f9286ddb560>

Comment: Right. You have only `@ejecutives = Ejecutive.find(:all)` and not one specific `Ejecutive`. Try `@ejecutives.first.name`

Comment: ok man is working but is only saving my first ejecutive. Is there any other way to save by ejecutive selected??

Comment: Perhaps one download link for each? But that is a different problem. Please clean up your code with the current learnings and start a new question.